# Explicitly set document.domain on every page

Tags: xss

Is is a good idea to set document.domain on every page of your site. For example if your site is 'www.example.com'. But you also work with 'en.example.com' and 'fr.example.com' and 'www.example.com:8444'. All these domains make it difficult to work with when you have to deal with xss issues. So is it a terrible idea to explicity set document.domain = 'example.com' on all pages?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. It means any other subdomain can do the same, so if ever one with a lower trust level comes along (like ads.example.com or survey.example.com) it may come back and bite you.